# I am getting only december month expenses details not all month using XLOOKUP and Query formula

Tags: google-sheets

created expenses track sheet in google sheet. but in dropdown list 2022 ALL MONTH EXPENSES (B2) result show only december month expense details. how to correct and show all month expenses details in 2022 ALL MONTH EXPENSES?

my code

=query(DATA!B2:D, "where month(B)+1="& month(xlookup(B2,DATA!H2:H,DATA!I2:I)),0)

my gogole sheet link u can correct

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rNB-ikqSPwgGJmA12mXD5aUq9tqsKlqpRMXQLyrVSts/edit?usp=sharing

pl dont add arrayformula,use xlookup formula

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For all month expenses you should avoid then the conditions inside the query. And add a 0 in XLOOKUP to exact match. You can try this:

```
=query(DATA!B2:D, IF(B2="2022 ALL MONTH EXPENSES","","where month(B)+1="& MOIS(xlookup(B2,DATA!H2:H,DATA!I2:I,,0))),0)
```